# How to start a service automatically after restarting a vagrant box?

Tags: elasticsearch, vagrant, ansible

I installed `elasticsearch` using [this](https://github.com/comperiosearch/vagrant-elk-box-ansible) role.

I do the following steps in the playbook:

```
---

- hosts: master
  sudo: true
  tags: elasticsearch
  roles:
    - ansible-elasticsearch
```

And then `vagrant up es-test-cluster`, where `es-test-cluster` is the name of the VM I mention in `VagrantFile`. I have given it a private IP `192.162.12.14`. The VM boot perfectly and after running `sudo service elasticsearch status` I get that the service is running on `192.162.12.14:9200` which is correct. But if I run `vagrant halt es-test-cluster` and then `vagrant up es-test-cluster` I see that the elasticsearch service is running any more.

I thought of doing this:

```
---

- hosts: master
  sudo: true
  tags: elasticsearch
  roles:
    - ansible-elasticsearch
  tasks:
  - name: Starting elasticsearch service if not running
    service: name=elasticsearch state=started
```

but even this does not help. This only runs when I boot for the first time.

How can start the service whenever I run `vagrant up`?

This is for Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Have you experimented with chkconfig?

Comment: Setting `enables=yes` in your `Starting elasticsearch service if not running` might help. (I'm not 100% sure if `vagrant up` equals boot in this context).

Comment: @knowhy I tried some ways to do that successfully. I updated my answer. I'll try what you suggested as well.

Comment: Your question boils down to "How do I autostart a service in <insert OS here>?".

Comment: As @UlrichEckhardt points out, it depends on your OS, and which version. I think we all assume this is some flavor of Linux, but depending on if it is Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS, etc., will change the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "enable" the service. This can be done with a single flag in your Ansible.

```
---
- hosts: master
  sudo: true
  tags: elasticsearch
  roles:
    - ansible-elasticsearch
  tasks:
  - name: Starting elasticsearch service if not running
    service:
      name: elasticsearch
      state: started
      enabled: true
```

Also, depending on which ansible-elasticsearch role you are using, it may already have a flag that you can pass to enable the service without the extra task. I know the role I used did.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. Much better than what I did!

Answer (score 0):

The solutions are for Debian packages. 
You can include the following in the `VagrantFile`:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "restart_es.sh"
```

where `restart_es.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVICE=elasticsearch;
sudo update-rc.d $SERVICE defaults 95 10
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
    echo "$SERVICE service running, everything is fine"
else
    echo "$SERVICE is not running"
    sudo /etc/init.d/$SERVICE start
fi
```

OR

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "restart_es.sh", run: "always"
```

where `restart_es.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVICE=elasticsearch;
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
    echo "$SERVICE service running, everything is fine"
else
    echo "$SERVICE is not running"
    sudo service $SERVICE start
fi
```

OR

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo service elasticsearch start", run: "always"
```

All three start the `elasticsearch` service when you restart the vagrant box.